# Disabling outbound connectivity on web servers

Tags: multisite, security

Is it a good idea to harden your web server by disabling outbound connectivity on them?

I am using RHEL 7 for a WordPress Multisite installation.

After disabling outbound connectivity, the dashboard has become extremely slow, and the plugins page does not list the latest available ones.

Could I still live with this? What are the biggest disadvantages?

Comment: Got downvoted but is a good question.  I think you are asking if you could disable out-bound initiated connections via firewall settings.  If you disabled all connectivity no-one could make requests to your WP server.  IMO, it is possible but you have to either write plugins or hack WP core to make it work.  The WP server makes a lot of outbound requests for: WP core version, plugin versions, various news/info, WP cron, etc.  The only out-bound request that I see as important is the WP cron.  You would have to maintain upgrades manually.

Comment: Found out how to do this without hacking.  See if my answer works for you.

Comment: Okay, so I must reword my question to use the term "disable outbound initiated connections" rather than "disable internet connecitivty"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses an HTTP class to make outbound requests.  These requests are mainly for plugin, themes and core updates; pull news/rss content; and make third party API requests.

There may be many different reasons for disabling outbound requests, security is the primary one.  A WP instance with disabled outbound requests is more secure.  Many institutions have intranets or secure networks that do not allow external requests.  If the outbound requests are not disabled within WP, then WP admin console will not function properly due to timeouts.

The main disadvantage of blocking outboud requests is blocking third party APIs or any external requests.  There are many plugins that will not function if you do so.

If you want to disable WP from making any outbound requests add these settings in wp-config.php:

`define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);  // block external requests
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true'); // block WP cron`

Answer (score 2):

The internet is a big mash of services communicating with each other. Semi dropping out of the network might have been a valid idea in 2000 but it sounds like a stupid idea in 2015 but the amount of damage depends on your site's functionality. If you don't need any 3rd party service on server side then you can do it, but as I said it is a very unlikely situation in 2015.

What kind of services will you loss? the easy to see are akismet and any of the "automatic" software updates, and this is probably just the start when you try to run a non trivial site.

Comment: It is definitely a nontrivial site. Looking at your answer, it seems the only purpose served is securing the site from carelessly installed plugins that set up backdoors. Am I right?

Comment: no, it is trivial to bypass any outbound restrictions as the site is on the internet and will accept traffic from any place. Plugin do need need to initiate any evil trafic, it can just wait untill it is pinged and then transfer its evil payload. IMHO The only thing that maybe prevented this way is DDOS style attacks.